# PHP infinite loop delay

Tags: php, loops, delay, repeat, infinite

I am trying to make a PHP loop with delay between the loop
this doens't work

```
<?php
$i=0;
while(true) {
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

I am trying to get this as an output:

```
1
[wait 1 second]

2
[wait 1 second]

3
[wait 1 second]

4
[wait 1 second]

5
[wait 1 second]

6
[wait 1 second]

...
```

Comment: Add another echo?

Comment: `this doens't work`. Could you explain what it does, what you expected it would do, etc? also: works on my machine

Comment: By default, PHP only sends output at the end of execution

Comment: patrick that is the problem

Comment: Do you want this output in the CLI (command line interface) or in the web?

Comment: it's not for a counter but for a checkloop

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer? According to GreatBigBore it doesn't answer your question, but I'd think it does. Let me know if it works for you and if it does, please upvote and mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flush and ob_flush to send the output to the browser before the script is completed:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$i=0;
while(true) {
  $i++;
  echo $i;
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19259998)

Comment: Does it not? @Zwarte Piet, have you tried my solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: The review system doesn't show comments by default. It just shows the question. Your code here will give him exactly what he showed in the question, so it didn't look helpful. Now I see that he left out the most important part of the question, and put it in the comments. Soon, other reviewers will come through and see the same thing I did, and they will vote to delete your answer as I did, and you'll get a disagreeable auto-message again. So, in addition to asking OP to put me in my place, you might also consider asking OP to fix his question, so it looks like your answer really is an answer.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with either the question or my answer. The OP wants to create a delayed output where something appears in the browser, then after a second more output and so on. Felt clear to me. My answer does just that.

Comment: I've done my part in trying to help you, warning you of what is likely to happen. What you do with the information I have generously offered to you is none of my business.